# Is it possible to do a custom category search in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using the Google Maps Javascript API with Google Places to search for stores, I can only search a specific list of categories or a specific string contained in each store name.  For example, if I don't pass the "types" parameter, but use the "name" parameter, it only pulls stores containing that name.

For example, if I search for "sporting goods", I only get stores like "Joe's Sporting Goods".  Stores like "Cabela's" aren't being returned since they don't contain that exact phrase.

Does anyone know how to search for a generic store type that isn't in Google's specific list of place "types"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out both `name=...` and `types=...` in the HTTP query. Then you get all places inside the specified distance and can filter them to find your favorites.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it still doesn't tell me a specific category or type of store, just that it's a "store" or an "establishment".  I'm looking to duplicate the search if a user goes to maps.google.com.